# Pass results back to main thread from neverending worker thread

Tags: android, multithreading, worker

in my Java application (specifically Android) I have a main thread which is doing all the major operations. Now there's an additional worker thread that does sensor interpretation endlessly. How can I pass values back to the main thread?

I've found ways to do that assuming the worker will shut down once it has a value. But in my case it doesn't stop (intentionally).

Best regards,

Jens

Comment: do you want to make changes on UI?

Comment: In the end - yes, I want to make changes to the UI.
I'll take a closer look at Handler.

I've noticed a very bad battery life when the thread is constantly using sensors. I'll modify it to use a Handler and only run for a limited time.